# Arduino software Serial unexpected output

Tags: sockets, arduino

I am trying to build a small software that returns NMEA sentences based on it's input,
Currently I am sending the following NMEA gps sentence over a software Serial:

```
$GPGGA,171751.148,5231.230,N,01323.004,E,1,12,1.0,0.0,M,0.0,M,,*64
$GPGSA,A,3,01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12,1.0,1.0,1.0*30
$GPRMC,171751.148,A,5231.230,N,01323.004,E,,,221220,000.0,W*71
```

When I use the Serial.println function I get the same output as the input which I want, If I do the exact same thing as the code below, I get only the first sentence `$GPGGA,171751.148,5231.230,N,01323.004,E,1,12,1.0,0.0,M,0.0,M,,*64`, So by changing the Serial.println to newSerial.println will only give me 1 result instead of the 3 above. How can I overcome this?

````
void loop() {
  if (newSerial.available() > 0 ) {
    // read incoming character from GPS and feed it to NMEA type object
    if (gps.decode(newSerial.read())) {
        newSerial.println (gps.sentence());
    }
      
  }
}```
````

Comment: neSerial.read returns an int, maybe this will work ?  `gps.decode((char)newSerial.read())`

Comment: thanks @MichaëlRoy, I think I need to search this problem a little deeper, It might be because software Serial is only half duplex, and is locking when reading/writing at around the same time?

Comment: I've never used NewSerial, but if it's only half duplex, then that would be it.  Half duplex only works when the two devices are aware if it and share the line cooperatively.

Comment: ... using hardware hanshaking is key to make half-duplex comms work.